# Creating multiple plots with for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary of dataframes where the key is the name of each dataframe and the value is the dataframe itself.

I am looking to iterate through the dictionary and quickly plot the top 10 rows in each dataframe. Each dataframe would have its own plot. I've attempted this with the following:

```
for df in dfs:
    data = dfs[df].head(n=10)
    sns.barplot(data=data, x='x_col', y='y_col', color='indigo').set_title(df)
```

This works, but only returns a plot for the last dataframe in the iteration. Is there a way I can modify this so that I am also able to return the subsequent plots?

Comment: Are you wanting a all the dfs in a grid of subplots (like 3x3)? Or a full, separate plot per df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, [seaborn.barplot()](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) plots data on the current Axes. If you didn't specify the Axes to plot on, the latter will override the previous one. To overcome this, you can either create a new figure in each loop or plot on a different axis by specifying the `ax` argument.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for df in dfs:
    data = dfs[df].head(n=10)
    plt.figure() # Create a new figure, current axes also changes.
    sns.barplot(data=data, x='x_col', y='y_col', color='indigo').set_title(df)
```